# Is there a way of changing the service status through the Nagios Web Interface?

Tags: nagios

Is there a way, either through the vanilla web interface or a plugin, to allow an authorized user to change the status of a service?

Or is it better to do so through the command line, just using `send_nsca`? I'm setting the service status through `send_ncsa`, however, it would be easier for the operator then to change the CRITICAL warning back to OK through the web interface.

Comment: Why do you want to change the status manually? It will change itself automatically when the problem is gone...

Comment: The scenario is that the server a critical status when a set amount of identical 500 errors appear in the same timeframe. Nagios is being used in this case to notify us that this threshold has been triggered. 

The problem does not "go" until someone looks at the problem, and decides if it's an issue or not. This is the part where he/she needs to set the critical back to ok.

Answer (score 2):

There is a button "Submit passive check result for this service" on the right which lets you submit a checkresult. However, this is no fun to repeat that action 500 times. Advanced guis like [Thruk](http://thruk.org) lets you submit results back to multiple services and hosts at once.